# What does this `ld` error ("undefined reference") mean?

Tags: c

What does this error mean?

```
/tmp/ccevEqoI.o: In function `main':
funcptr.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `AddALL'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm trying to write a function which adds all the integers up to the limit
entered by the user.

---

Transcribed 'answer' which is a comment from the OP:

> I wrote a program that would add all the integers upto the limit Specified. For that I had to write a function. So I made a function called 'AddAll' but when I called it from my program I called it as 'AddALL'.
>
> Note: **C is case sensitive**. Eventually when I changed the name of the function where I was calling it. It compiled perfectly :)
>
> Just thought that this piece of info would be useful to beginners.

Comment: You should have gotten a warning during the compile stage that there was no prototype for AllALL (and that the compiler was assuming a return type of int).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It tells you that the definition for the function 'AddALL' could not be found. Make sure that you include the object file that contains 'AddALL' when you compile/link.

Comment: Coming back here in shame after almost pulling my hair out. If anyone lands here after seeing `ld: error: undefined symbol` in your c++ Cmake project, make sure your cpp file (in addition to the header file) is also listed in your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Answer (score 9):

It means that the linker (that is called `ld` in gcc) did not found the symbol `AddALL` in the specified object files. Basically, there is no body for that function or it's a variable declared as `extern` with no definition.